# Algorithm help needed - rows/columns in a grid

Tags: android

I have been killing myself trying to develop an algorithm to determine the positions of the cells in a grid by which row or column they are in.

For example, I have an 8x8 grid and I need to determine all of the positions of the cells in row 3.

The issue that I have is that, without alot of loops, I need to figure out a way to map the position clicked to the row and column that contain that cell.

Here is what I did to create an ArrayList of the cells:

```
public class GameBoard {
public ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
public ArrayList<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();

private int maxPositions;

public GameBoard(int rowCount, int colCount) {
    this.maxPositions = (rowCount * colCount) - 1;

    for(int x = 0;x < rowCount;x++){
        Row row = new Row(x);
        row.cells.addAll(this.getRowCells(x, colCount));
        rows.add(row);
    }

    for(int x = 0;x < colCount;x++){
        Column column = new Column(x);
        column.cells.addAll(getColumnCells(x, colCount));
        columns.add(column);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Cell> getRowCells(int rowId, int colCount) {
    ArrayList<Cell> row_cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    int first_position  = ((rowId * colCount) -1);
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.id = first_position;
    row_cells.add(cell);
    int x = 1;
    while(x < colCount) {
        cell = new Cell();
        cell.id = first_position + x;
        row_cells.add(cell);
        x++;
    }
    return row_cells;       
}

private ArrayList<Cell> getColumnCells(int columnId, int rowCount) {
    ArrayList<Cell> col_cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    int first_position  = columnId;
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.id = first_position;
    col_cells.add(cell);
    int x = 1;
    while(x < rowCount) {
        cell = new Cell();
        cell.id = rows.get(x).cells.get(columnId).id;
        col_cells.add(cell);
        x++;
    }
    return col_cells;
}

public Cell getColumnNextCell(int position, int columnId) {
    Cell cell = null;
    if ((position > -1) && (position <= maxPositions)) {
        cell = columns.get(columnId).cells.get(position + 1);
    }
    return cell;
}

public Cell getColumnPreviousCell(int position, int columnId) {
    Cell cell = null;
    if ((position > 0) && (position <= maxPositions)) {
        cell = columns.get(columnId).cells.get(position - 1);
    }
    return cell;
}

public Cell getRowNextCell(int position, int rowId) {
    Cell cell = null;
    if ((position > -1) && (position <= maxPositions)) {
        cell = rows.get(rowId).cells.get(position + 1);
    }
    return cell;
}

public Cell getRowPreviousCell(int position, int rowId) {
    Cell cell = null;
    if ((position > 0) && (position <= maxPositions)) {
        cell = rows.get(rowId).cells.get(position - 1);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

}

As you can see with the methods like getColumnNextCell() through getRowPreviousCell() the logic is a mess and I am stuck on how to determine the column and row of the clicked cell (as I explained). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For clarification the Row and Column objects are identical. They look like this.

```
public class Column {
public int id;
public ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

public Column(int idx) {
    this.id = idx;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use an array for the cells

```
int rows, cols;
Cell[][] cells;

public GameBoard(int rowCount, int colCount) {
    this.maxPositions = (rowCount * colCount) - 1;

    this.rows = rowCount;
    this.cols = colCount;
    this.cells = new Cell[rows];
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        cells[i] = new Cell[cols];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            cells[i][j] = new Cell();
            // whatever else you need to do...
        }
    }
}
```

This way it would be easy to get the cell you want

```
Cell getCell(int position) {
     return cells[position/rows][position%cols];
}
```

Comment: Thanks... you set me on the right path. It wasn't exactly what I needed but it helped alot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple two dimensional array? If your grid is not resized after creation, there is no advantage of using ArrayList objects. So what about having your base class something like this:

```
public class GameBoard {
  private Cell[][] cells;
  private int maxPositions;
  private int rows;
  private int cols;

  public GameBoard(int rowCount, int colCount) {
    this.rows = rowCount;
    this.cols = colCount;
    cells = new Cell[rowCount][colCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
        cells[i][j] = new Cell();
      }
    }
    this.maxPositions = (rowCount * colCount) - 1;
  }
  ...
}
```

Now you don't have row and column objects, just array of cells. Isn't those cells actually what you need or do those row and column arrays have another purpose? So I think you are trying to do simple thing with too difficult way.